# Change default print program for images on Windows 2003 SP2

Tags: windows, printing, file-association, fax

I would like to change the default program used to print images on Windows 2003. And this is why...

I'm using a "pro" fax software that uses 3rd party applications as hosts to render the specific "documents" to the fax/printer driver.

So for instance docx will launch Word, pdf will launch Foxit Reader and so on. It works by somehow launching the programs and clicking through the dialog boxes. It's basically right clicking the file and then hitting print and then checking Windows events for the Print dialog. The caveat to this is that any extra dialog boxes that may appear such as a help wizard or update manager will block the process. All fax software vendors recommend to go through the programs and disable any special dialog boxes that may appear. So far it works for Word and Foxit. It can work for images too but have to find the proper print program.

All this to say is that by default in Windows Picture Fax Viewer opens a Print Wizard dialog. I would like to change the Print association to Paint for most/all images.

Comment: You say you are using windows 2003, you mean windows server 2003?

Answer (score 0):

You mention making the default Print program as Paint.
Entering the print dialog supplied by Paint means associating those file types you want with Paint.

A simple way, right click on the type of file you want to associate with Paint
[image]

Then select Open With and a list of installed programs will display.
Select what you want and make sure to check the "Always use the selected program to open this file type"
[image]

OR
right click the an example file of that type and select Properties,
Press the change button and you will get to the same dialog where you can select the default program.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't set the Print association though.

It opens in paint but when I right click and hit Print... The Picture/Fax viewer Wizard still appears.

Comment: I wasted quite a bit of time in explorer>tools>folder options>file types>selecting jpeg and advanced which gives you the ability to set a printto command for the file type, BUT nothing worked for me, Even tried adding a registry key. If the image is opened in mspaint, then the print dialog comes from mspaint. Getting windows to respect that on the right-click or double-click I can't get to happen either, sorry. It seems like it should be changeable but I am at a loss